# VBA, select all chart filter

Tags: vba, excel

How do I select all for chart filters?

Filtering out in vba is

```
  ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(1).IsFiltered = True
```

and filtering in is

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(1).IsFiltered = False
```

The above is done for 1 data point, But how do you select all to filter in(or select all)

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through them all:

```
Sub UnfilterCategories()
  Dim iCat As Long, nCat As Long
  With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1)
    nCat = .FullCategoryCollection.Count
    For iCat = 1 To nCat
      .FullCategoryCollection(iCat).IsFiltered = False
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```